# Possible error with Stanford POS Tagger and classifying intent and the replies

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have a specific usecase, where a person would say something like this:

- ***"Hey (Trigger Word), note in object history XYZ"*** or:
- ***"Hey (Trigger Word), record in object diagnosis that PQR"***
- ("object" as used in the example is a placeholder and can be replaced with words like 'Maintenance/Patient', etc.)

I would like to recognize the intent and the slots.

Then I use Stanford Parser to parse the sentence, e.g. parsing ***"Note in object history object was last updated in may twenty eighteen"*** gives this list-of-tuple:

```
[('Note', 'VB'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('object', 'NN'),
 ('history', 'NN'),
 ('object', 'NN'),
 ('was', 'VBD'),
 ('last', 'RB'),
 ('updated', 'VBN'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('may', 'MD'),
 ('twenty', 'CD'),
 ('eighteen', 'CD')]
```

1. Now, my point is how can I use this information to get the necessary output:

   - Where to note *(we have a field in DB: Object History)* and
   - What to note *(object was last updated in may twenty eighteen)*.
2. Another issue is since the input of the NLP is from an ASR system, the capitalization is missing. And the POS Tagger mis-tags 'note' as 'NN' (instead of 'VB'). Ideally 'note'/'record' should be a verb. How do I solve this probable error?

Comment: You could simply delete the *"Hey (Trigger Word), "* preamble, then capitalize the next word (*"Note"/"Record"/etc.). If POSTagger still misclassifies that as NN, you could keep a list of known action-verbs that commonly start a sentence, and kludge the first item the POS output. (But also file a bug on POSTagger)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall keep this in mind. Now another added query is for part 1. What kind of chunking will help me get part two of the sentence (what to note). I can get where to note from chunking "note in location", but I'm still not sure how to get the part: what to note. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TrueCaseAnnotator to fix case issues:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/truecase.html

In general you probably just want to use TokensRegex and write rules patterns to handle these templates.  More info here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I shall also try and use tokensregex and see how that can be useful. Thanks a lot.